# When to use Configure() to set up dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I understand the differences between `AddTransient()`, `AddScoped()` and `AddSingleton()` when configuring services. But I'm having trouble finding good information about `Configure()`.

It seems I can use them all interchangeably. The only real difference I see is that when you use `Configure()`, you have to deal with that somewhat annoying `IOptions` component.

Are there hard and fast rules about when I should use `Configure()` instead any of the `Add...` methods? Can someone link to a good article on this. (Every time I Google it, I just get a discussion on the differences between `AddTransient()`, `AddScoped()` and `AddSingleton()`.)

Comment: [ConfigureServices vs Configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421940/7450780) 
ConfigureServices - Adding services to the container and will make them available for dependency injection.
Configure - Configure http request pipeline (add middlewares,authorization... etc)

Comment: @DenisMicheal: Thanks, but that is explaining the difference between `Configure` and `ConfigureServices`. I'm asking about the difference between `Configure` and `AddTransient`, `AddScoped` or `AddSingleton`.

Comment: Why is the IOptions pattern "somewhat annoying"?

Comment: @PaulCarlton: Because I'm after the data structure and `IOptions` just adds another layer between DI and that structure.

Comment: @JonathanWood - using configure, I've found ioptions to be very usable and actually quite convenient.  It provides for you a means of retrieving configurable data based on environment, configuration options on the command during build, as well as the standard for access to configurables in web/console/mvc and blazor apps.  Maybe you just haven't used it enough to get used to it.  There's enough there to be convenient, and enough absent for you to be able to utilize it in a custom way depending on your app's needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

---

OP's question is actually on `service.Configure<>` vs `AddTransient()`, `AddScoped()` and
`AddSingleton()`.

I will just supplement on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431790/7450780).

[service.Configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions-configure-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration))

> Registers a configuration instance that TOptions will bind against,
> and updates the options when the configuration changes.

it's used to bind a section of the configuration to a strongly typed object. It allows you to define options by binding configuration sections to instances of classes representing those options.

From [source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,2aa74bb06c82c8f7), You will see this method under the hood eventually does the following:

- Add `IOptionsSnapshot<>` service with lifetime Scoped.
- Add `IOptionsMonitor<>` service with lifetime Singleton.
- Add `IOptionsFactory<>` service with lifetime transient.
- Add `IOptionsMonitorCache<>` with Singleton lifetime.
- Add `IOptions<>` with Singleton Lifetime to DI Container.

As far as using `AddTransient` or `AddScoped` to add `IOptions<TOptions>` is inadvisable, if you want to read configuration changes take a look at [IOptionsMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0),[IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionssnapshot-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: There is a small misunderstanding. The question is about the [the Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#the-options-pattern), e.g.: `builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));` vs `builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyOptions>();`